# Running program from a remote machine

Tags: ssh, remote, matlab

I am currently working with 2 machines. Machine 1 has Matlab installed, and I have a large amount of data in Machine 2 that needs to be processed with Matlab. Copying the data from Machine 2 to Machine 1 is not viable. Is there any way I can run Matlab from Machine 1 to process files on the Machine 2?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can share the data over the network using NFS or SSHFS. Might take a huge performance hit.

Comment: +1 on  Muru's answer. If your problem is that machine 1 doesn't have enough disk space, using a shared filesystem (Samba would also work) is the best option. If the problem is that the network is too slow, then Matlab reading from a network drive will probably also be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what the above comments mentioned, you will need to share the file system with the data from machine 2 back to machine 1.

Enabling NFS is probably what you will want and a simple HowTo at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo is a good start to just get a basic setup for testing.

Next you will likely want to performance optimize and this following article is a decent beginnning: http://www.slashroot.in/how-do-linux-nfs-performance-tuning-and-optimization